# Xamarin Studio Targeting netstandard

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio, .net-standard-1.5

I am trying to upgrade my pcl library to target the netstandard in Xamarin Studio on my Mac. But I don't see the option. All the information I have found only talk about using Visual Studio.

[Xamarin Blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/)
[Oren's blog](https://oren.codes/2016/06/23/portable-is-dead-long-live-netstandard/)

When I look for the option they talk about in Xamarin Studio, I can't find it.

[image: No netstandard mentioned]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of `Xamarin Studio 6.0.2` you can consume .Net Standard libs, but NOT create them.

> The ability to **create** .NET Standard Libraries in Xamarin Studio on macOS will be available in the future, but today we are pleased to release Xamarin Studio 6.0.2 which supports consuming and compiling these libraries.

ref: https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/

Comment: Random update:  Looks like support is in 6.2 (which is current in beta -> https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.2/xamarin.studio_6.2/)